# Augmented reality help

Tags: video, augmented-reality

Im trying to do the following and I would like if its possible before losing too much time on it.

I want to use something like FLARToolKit to do the following: Upon detecting a marker the object to be shown is a video on 2d plane.

Anyone has done it or has some examples/tutorials? How hard will it be to implement?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this yet, however I know it's pretty simple.

Check this tutorial out, it should be more than enough to get your started as it does exactly as you want and more, the Video is moved in the 3D space.

http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=114